# How to write a List of a specific type using kryo serializer

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, parquet, kryo

I am trying to write a List of a specific type using Kryo serializer but I am getting errors when I try to read/write it. I am using source provided by apache spark for KryoRegistrator

List I am trying to write is of type `List<A>` which could be an ArrayList or any other type of list

Code

```
Class FakeRegsitrator implements KryoRegistrator{

  @Override
  public void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
      CollectionSerializer listSerializer = new CollectionSerializer();
      listSerializer.setElementClass(A.class, kryo.getSerializer(A.class));
      listSerializer.setElementsCanBeNull(false);

      kryo.register(A.class, new Serializer<A>(true, true) {
         public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, A a) {
             output.writeLong(a.getFieldA)
             output.WriteString(a.getFieldB)
         }
         public A read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class type) {
             return new A(input.readLong(), input.readString())
         }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by registering Arraylist.class

code :

```
kryo.register(ArrayList.class);

in read method use 
kryo.readObject(input, ArrayList.class);

in write method use
kryo.writeObject(output, entry.getArchivePortions());
```